# How to convert an iOS MonoTouch application into an Android version using Mono for Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

We have heard about the possibility to develop in C# on iOS and Android platforms using MonoTouch and Mono for Android

http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid

I have an *iOS MonoTouch* application that I would like to convert into a *Mono for Android* version.
How would a simple example, like the piece of code below, translate into Mono for Android?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace HelloWorld_iPhone
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can share code but not whole applications - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656092/code-sharing-between-monotouch-and-monoforandroid

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view.. Mean We are not able to convert whole ios monotouch application into android monotouch application.........

Comment: Yes Manoj, you are absolutely right.There is no way to achieve your concern due to UI limitation of MONOTOUCH.For bringing the Native look and feel it provides the different piece of code as device specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use of a `static void Main()` method in Mono for Android.  You basically have a "Main" activity that starts your app.

Here is an example of this:

```
[Activity (Label="My App", MainLauncher=true)]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{

}
```

This then generates the appropriate Android manifest file to launch the app. [See here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml).

I would just use `File->New Project->Mono for Android App` and use what the template generates.

Comment: So Monotouch is 20% mean of Cross platform.it is really weird to listen that its cross platform.

Comment: MonoTouch gives you the best of both worlds.  You take advantage of Google and Apple's native UIs (which can't be shared), and can reuse all of your C# backend code.  If you code your application correctly, you should be able to get between 40-60% shared code.  We also have developed a game (using MonoGame) that has 99% shared code, but that is not the norm for a standard app.

Comment: Yes, But in case of UI specific application Where i have 80% work for best to get 'look and feel' then it is really worthless.How can i use the common code for the UI in different devices(Android & iPhone).isn't it ?

Comment: That 80% of the work you mention could be the difference between a successful app and an unsuccessful one.  It is not even 80%, but more like 50% for an experienced developer.  If you are that concerned of 100% code sharing, then use MonoGame.  You can share near 100% of the code between platforms using it, but you will have to write any UI controls yourself--it is meant for games.  This is not the best option for all apps though, because your app might not necessarily feel "native" at all.

Comment: yeah, that is why I think Monotouch is not as successful as other Cross platforms like Titanium, phoneGame, Sencha touch. If we are making App for both of the platform (Android, iPhone) then only its good to go with any Cross platform OtherWise native Environment (SDK) must be choosen. Really Titanium, PhoneGap are covering market rapidly in this reference.

Comment: If you don't mind having a non-native experience, sure those other solutions could work for you.  You realize your app runs in a full screen browser (UIWebView on iOS) using these other solutions, right?  I personally prefer delivering a vivid native experience in my apps.

Comment: I am sorry to say but in case of Titanium It brings completely native experience for you, you need to acces in-built API Suports.Yes, in case of Phonegap, UIWebView is all in all.But the best part of these three platforms is their common code for controllers as well as for their UI implementation......where Monotouch fails us.

Comment: I think this is where you have a disconnect. When you using MonoTouch/MonoDroid, you should share ViewModels across all platforms (which have no hard dependency on UI elements). This makes your app completely *testable* via unit tests. Platforms specific code becomes very simple this way, a controller would merely invoke a ViewModel. Sharing controllers and tying yourself to a particular UI framework is not a good idea if you eventually want to port your app to Windows 8 (WinRT), the web, desktop Mac, etc. Xamarin is the best option for port your app to *every* platform, not just mobile.