# How cross-platform is Monotouch/Mono for Android development?

Tags: mobile, mono, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android

I am a python programmer looking to make my first mobile app. I'd like to make make an app for both iOS and Android that looks and feels native. I thought I'd start with a simple iPhone app, just to see how everyting works. Mono seems like the obvious solution. However, I was surprised to find that almost all of the example Monotouch code I found, as well as the answers here on Stackoverflow, relied heavily on the IOS frameworks, essentially making the code not cross-platform at all. For example, I was looking into using a timer. All the examples I read use NSTimer. Surely this is possible to do in C# itself so that that part is cross platform? But then, why do all these people use NSTimer?

So, my question is, how cross platform is Mono development for IOS/Android? Is it still worth considering for smallish apps, or only for very large apps with lots of business logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code sharing between MonoTouch and MonoForAndroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656092/code-sharing-between-monotouch-and-monoforandroid)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is too general. I'll answer it for two scenarios:

**Specific examples**
If you are looking for how do create timers, create arrays, traverse lists, then why not just look for regular .NET examples and compile this into a single class library that can be in both projects.

**Sharing code as a whole**
If you just mean in general sharing of code between the two platforms, you should look at frameworks that already have the templates and examples created for you. Two such patterns are http://www.monocross.net/ (MVC) and [mvvmcross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) (MVVM). This can help you architect your project from the beginning to support cross-platform development (iOS, Droid, Wp7, desktop, etc).

There are timers, arrays, and strings in the .NET Base Class Library. As you have seen, there are some in the Cocoa library that MonoTouch wraps. For example you have your regular run of the mill string in .NET, but in monotouch you also have the option of NSString. I think to answer your question, the reason people may use the iOS specific types sometimes, is either because they weren't trying to make that code cross-platform and it was a matter of preference, or they had to do something specifically that required the use of that type which wouldn't be the case for everyone.

Mono's purpose isn't just to help with cross-platform development. I come from a C#/.NET background so even if I was building an app with one screen and two buttons, I would use MonoTouch because I would rather use C# with the .NET BCL than Obj-C. But that is my own personal choice and enough of a deciding factor, for me.

**EDIT**
I added the links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What surprised me wasn't so much that people use things like NSTimer (and NSString indeed) but more that they also often appear in general recommendations to others (for example on monotouchexamples.com). Of course when cross-platform isn't a requirement there is no reason not to use those classes and personal preference is a perfectly valid reason. I just wanted to know that that's all it was, and not some reason about mono/C# itself. I will check out MVC and MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point is that in order to use Mono and NOT use platform specific types etc like NSSTring you need a platform specific wrapper (abstraction layer) that lets you write code that only uses Mono types.

i.e. You are asking about using Mono but what you actually need are MonoTouch and MonoDroid (the frameworks referenced by @valdetero, depend on having those wrappers underpinning them).