# Common library for monodroid and desktop applications

Tags: android, .net, mono, xamarin.android

I am currently starting a project which I would like to develop both a Android and desktop app for using [mono for android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).  I would like to encapsulate the common logic into a shared library but at the moment I am unsure of how to accomidate both frameworks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create projects using the "Android Class Library" project template because the mscorlib supported by monodroid(v2.0.5.0) is lower then the MSFX2.0 (v2.0.50727)

Comment: @Brian, the way I'm handling it in my won cross-platform library (PC, Mac, Xbox, WP7, Android, iOS) is to create a core library as a .NET 4.0 framework targetted library. This contains all the shared/base functionality. I've then created copies of this core library targetting the appropriate platforms. There are ways of managing this that can become complicated, in my case I'm just adding all the files as links.

After all that you create additional libraries for platform-specific functionality or you can include partial classes rather than inheritance.

Comment: I'd created a new Solution with an "Android Class Library" and a "Windows Application", referenced AndroidClassLibrary1 Project and it worked like a charm... VS Solution Explorer shows an "warning yellow triangle" under reference but it compiled withou problems.

Comment: I have been trying the same thing, but unfortunately MonoDevelop does not allow for the project to compile.  And when I use Visual Studio and do as you do, I find I cannot debug the Android Class Library.  While I agree that this is the best solution at the moment, I believe that there still needs to be interoperability improvements to MonoDroid before we can hit the holy grail solution.

Comment: @Brian, you may be facing an bug on Mono under VS because I'm debugging library pretty well, I did not buy the license because the last update just broke the Layout Designer. Do you requested support?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create separate class library projects for each platform, and then share the source files across them. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656092/code-sharing-between-monotouch-and-monoforandroid) has a lot of links and details about how to go about doing that.